Best GPS Devices to easily interface with an NVIDIA Jetson and ROS2?
I want to track a moving robot with <10m accuracy, however, I don't even know where to begin looking. I acquired a Garmin 18x LVC, however, I don't know how to interface with it (any help would be appreciated). Thus, I'm looking for alternatives to use that I could just connect to my laptop via USB cable and then read GPS information off of it. Any suggestions?

Many choices you have there as the question is broad, but you can take a look at uBlox-ZED-F9P as a reference. If I remember correctly, it costs around 200 Pounds. It has UART support which allows you to read data on your laptop just with a USB cable.
Of course, you need to decode the data you receive from the UART line, however, thankfully there are third-party projects which do the work for you, such as the ublox-driver from HKUST Aerial Robotics group. On the repository page it says the project has ROS support.
The accuracy part is dependent by the way. However uBlox supports DGNSS which allows for positions solutions that meet your requirement easily.
